# Why is Stokes theorem not applicable / not used correctly in this case?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

I am doing some exercises and I don't understand what is wrong with my solution here.

The problem is: given the integral $$ I = \int_S (1 + x^2) f(x) dydz - 2xy f(x) dz dx - 3z dx dy$$

Find such a continuously differentiable function $f$ such that the integral $I$ is equal for all surfaces $S$, whose border is a circle $ C := \{ (\cos t, \sin t, 1) \; | \; t \in [0, 2 \pi ] \}$ and then calculate the integral $I$.

My thinking is that any function that is defined everywhere and $C^1$ should be alright! Let's denote $\overrightarrow{R}$ the vector field over which we are integrating. For any well defined $C^1$ function $f(x)$, field $\overrightarrow{R}$ will be well defined and $C^1$. Then by Stokes theorem we have:

$$ \int_S rot \overrightarrow{R} d\vec{S} = \int_{\partial S} \overrightarrow{R} d \vec{r}$$

where $\partial S = C$, which is a fixed number, so the integral on the left will be equal for every surface $S$ with the same border.

However, the  solution uses Gauss's theorem instead and shows that the sufficient condition is that $div \overrightarrow{R} = 0$. It also states (without proof) that this condition is also necessary.

To sum up, I would appreciate if you help me figure out

1. What is wrong with my reasoning using Stokes theorem?
2. How to show that $div \overrightarrow{R} = 0$ is a necessary condition?

Comment: Hypotheses aside, the general version of this theorem looks like: $\int_Xd\omega = \int_{\partial X}\omega$. So the answer to this question requires finding $\omega$ with the given info. I.e. design $\omega$ with choice of $f(x)$ such that $d\omega$ is as above. What you have written for the integral equality is missing "curl" and dot products. This is not divergence theorem. If we try to apply the Poincare Lemma, we need to show $d("d\omega")= 0$, this forces $f(x) = 3tan^{-1}(x)$ for it to be closed. Though this doesn't give the $\omega$ we need for the rest of the problem.

Comment: @KevinS Oh I missed the rotor I dont know how, I fixed that now. But still, wouldn't then the solution be any field that has a vector potential? Oh, just as I'm writing this, this is actually characterised (for star domains) by having div = 0. Is this reasoning with Stokes theorem (not even necessarily the general one) also correct?

Comment: I don't see how divergence theorem applies especially considering that we don't know the surface $S$ encloses a volume. I've also tried considering the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals (with a potential thrown in there) but it didn't work out for me. What did work, I posted in the answer section. To proceed to the finish there requires some Calc. 2, trig-integral techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in a chart for a differential 1-form (using Einstein conv.) looks like:
$$\omega = \omega_idx^i$$
$$\implies d\omega  = d\omega_i \wedge dx^i = \partial_j\omega_idx^j\wedge dx^i.$$
For $n=3$, we have (invoking multilinearity and skew-symmetry of $\wedge$) that:
$$d\omega = (\partial_x\omega_idx\wedge dx^i)+(\partial_y\omega_idy\wedge dx^i) + (\partial_z\omega_idz\wedge dx^i)$$
$$= \bigg(\partial_x\omega_1dx\wedge dx+\partial_x\omega_2dx\wedge dy+\partial_x\omega_3dx\wedge dz\bigg)+\bigg(\partial_y\omega_1dy\wedge dx+\partial_y\omega_2dy\wedge dy+\partial_y\omega_3dy\wedge dz\bigg)+\bigg(\partial_z\omega_1dz\wedge dx+\partial_z\omega_2dz\wedge dy+\partial_z\omega_3dz\wedge dz\bigg)$$
$$= (\partial_x\omega_2-\partial_y\omega_1)dx\wedge dy + (\partial_y\omega_3-\partial_z\omega_2)dy\wedge dz+(\partial_x\omega_3-\partial_z\omega_1)dx\wedge dz$$
$$= (\partial_y\omega_3-\partial_z\omega_2)dydz+(\partial_z\omega_1-\partial_x\omega_3)dzdx+(\partial_x\omega_2-\partial_y\omega_1)dxdy.$$

---

Since we have:
$$d\omega := (1+x^2)f(x)dydz-2xyf(x)dzdx-3zdxdy$$
Combinining with the above gives a system that $\omega$ satisfies:
$$(i)\text{ }\partial_y\omega_3 - \partial_z\omega_2 = (1+x^2)f(x)$$
$$(ii)\text{ } \partial_z\omega_1 - \partial_x\omega_3 = -2xyf(x)$$
$$(iii)\text{ } \partial_x\omega_2 - \partial_y\omega_1 = -3z$$

---

Now, bear with me as I proceed to find (a) solution to this system (not claiming uniqueness). If we assume that:
$$\omega_3 \equiv 0,$$
then (i) and (ii) simplify to:
$$\partial_z\omega_2 = -(1+x^2)f(x)$$
$$\partial_z\omega_1 = -2xyf(x)$$
Integrating these with respect to $z$ gives:
$$\omega_1 = -2xyzf(x)+G_1(x,y)$$
$$\omega_2 = -z(1+x^2)f(x)+G_2(x,y)$$
where $G_i(x,y)$ are constants of integration w.r.t. $z$.
Let's assume these vanish identically as well. Then combining these results with (iii) gives:
$$\partial_x\omega_2 - \partial_y\omega_1 = -z[2xf(x)+(1+x^2)f'(x)] +2xzf(x)$$
$$=-z(1+x^2)f'(x) = -3z$$
Assuming $z\neq 0$ and $x\neq i$ gives:
$$f'(x) = \frac{3}{1+x^2}$$
Or equivalently:
$$f(x) = 3tan^{-1}(x)+C.$$
This is a good reaffirmation of the exactness discussion!
Take $C=0$.

---

Putting this all together gives (a) primitive:
$$\omega = (-6xyz\cdot tan^{-1}(x))dx+(-3z(1+x^2)\cdot tan^{-1}(x))dy$$
Provided $z\neq 0$ (which won't matter over $C$).

---

Finally, in your application of Stoke's Theorem:
$$I = \int_Sd\omega = \int_{\partial S = C}\omega$$
So dump in the parameterization for $C$ $\bigg($i.e. $(x,y,z)(t) = (cos(t),sin(t),1)\bigg)$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$ and the result will follow!